# Separating Websocket Publisher

Tags: spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have an application which has push message to client. My application built using spring [boot, security, websocket, angularjs-1]. When user login and accessing a page, user automatically subscribed to multiple end-point (url).

And then, on the same application I have a service which listen to a rabbitmq. Message on rabbitmq contains url where it will pushed + data. Whenever rabbitmq contain a message, this service will push the message to url on message.

Will my application be slow because of this pusher? Or maybe it's effect just a little bit.

I try to separate the pusher, as a daemon/jar application. When this application get message from rabbitmq, application push the message well, but user never get the message. Maybe because user login and subscribe to another application (my first application)

What the best solution for this? Is it possible to separate the pusher? Or maybe it is no problem to merged it, because the effect just a little.

This is how I push the message

```
@Autowired
SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

public void publishNewItemsState(String itemId, String[] message){
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/area.idsubscribed/"+itemId+"/mc1t1h", message);
}
```

*Sorry for my bad English, and I am a newcomer in websocket*